# Last access time for a GCP CloudSQL MySQL database

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

How to get last access time for a `GCP CloudSQL Server MySQL` database ?

I was using the following query in `GCP Logging` to get the above info

```
     resource.type="cloudsql_database"
     resource.labels.database_id="gis-myproject-tst-1ba3:sql-tst-mysql-checks"
     logName="projects/gis-myproject-tst-1ba3/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access"
     severity=(INFO OR NOTICE)
```

This gives me the info when the database was last accessed from `GCP Console` . But I want additional info like when it was last accessed using tool like `mysql` or from a `cloud function , Cloud run` etc programs.

Comment: can you look into my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

For MYSQL Server you can use the `mysql.general_log` table like provided in this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html)
But firstly we need to turn on the general_log but be sure to turn it off after troubleshooting:

```
SET GLOBAL log_output='TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log='ON';
```

Then to get last accessed time run:

```
SELECT event_time FROM mysql.general_log ORDER BY event_time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This will return the last access time for your CloudSQL instance.
Then turn off the general_log as it will affect performance of that instance.

```
SET GLOBAL general_log='OFF';
```

Although you can also see the logs for that instance using your required resource type as described in this [documentations](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/logging#view_logs)